# Ruby error: undefined method `casecmp' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code (with a few debug lines added):

Ruby:

```
re_dict = {}
re_dict['state'] = 'pending' #set initial status to pending
puts re_dict, re_dict.class.to_s
puts re_dict['state'], re_dict['state'].class.to_s
puts re_dict['state'].casecmp('pending')
while re_dict['state'].casecmp('pending') == 0 do
    stuff
end
```

Output

```
state: pending
state class: String
class compared to 'pending': 0
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 66ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `casecmp' for nil:NilClass):
```

What is causing this? How am I losing the value of my hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen only when you remove `'state'` key from `re_dict` hash inside your while loop:

```
while re_dict['state'].casecmp('pending') == 0 do
  puts re_dict
  re_dict = {}
end
#=> {"state"=>"pending"}
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `casecmp' for nil:NilClass
```

Since, key `'state'` is not available anymore, calling `re_dict['state']` will give `nil`, that's why you're getting `undefined method casecmp' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Well, I feel foolish... I am working with another coder. My code asks his for a status. His code changed.

Comment: Turned out to be a peer programming glitch.. No need to feel that way. Has happened to me, too.  :)